# PHP - Editing array and re-saving in csv file

Tags: php, arrays, csv, edit

My problem is that I cannot edit an array and save it.

I have two csv files. I managed to search users data and save that searched data to another csv file. Called 'SearchData.csv'.
At the moment I have:

This saves the searched data to the new csv file 'SearchData':

```
 // Grabs the csv file (and its existing data)  and makes it into an array
$EditResults = array();

$lines = file('SearchData.csv', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);

foreach ($lines as $key => $value)
{
    $EditResults[$key] = str_getcsv($value);
}
```

Once this occurs it also redirects to a new page. Where it will check each line. If the line has a value in the first cell of that row, then it prints out a mini form for that row.

```
for ($i=0; $i<200; $i++) {
    if(empty($SearchResults[$i][0]) == false){ //If its full
    
    ?>
  <form method="post">

  Full Name: <input name = "Name" type="text" value="<?php echo $SearchResults[$i][0] ?>"/>
   
  Weight (kg): <input name="Weight" type="number" value="<?php echo $SearchResults[$i][1] ?>"/>
  
 Weight of belongings (kg): <input name="WeightOfBelongings" type="number"value="<?php echo $SearchResults[$i][2] ?>"/>

  </form>
```

I cannot manage to get the 'update' button to work, which will update the values of each person in the main csv file called 'data.csv'. (It should work out their names and find them in the csv file - updating their weight etc.)

I hope this is the best way to do it. I could not work out how to make a table editable and save that...

Here's an image of what it looks like at the moment:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: "This saves the searched data to the new csv file" - no, it does not. The code you've share writes data to an array, not to a file. Please share the code that you are facing problems with, along with your attempts to resolve the problem